# Extracting with .find() the second of 2 identical 'div' from html page with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the second of 2 identical 'div' from a a soup element. When parsing trough and extracting with the .find() method, it gets exclusively the first from the top. How can I tell the script to skip the first and get the next one if some conditions are met? Here below is the html code I want to extract from.

```
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>MPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)</span></div>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="sg-1"><div class="sg-2">
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-base">
</div>
</div>
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-mini">
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>$0.00 with a CONtv trial on Prime Video Channels</span></div>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm trying:

```
if '$' not in str(product.find('div', {'class': 'a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary'})):
    print('NOT IN')
    pass
    price = product.find('div', {'class': 'a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary'})
    print(price)
else:
    price = product.find('div', {'class': 'a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary'})
    print(price)
```

However as results it still gives me this:

```
NOT IN
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>MPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)</span></div>
```

Rather then this:

```
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>$0.00 with a CONtv trial on Prime Video Channels</span></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `find_all` then index into returned list as `find` only ever returns first match. You can do same thing with `select`. With bs4 4.7.1. you can use `:contains` to target `innerText` of element by a substring (e.g. `CONtv trial`) and then use `select_one` if first match wanted or `select` if multiple matches. You want to test `if None` first before attempting to access `.text`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

html = '''
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>MPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)</span></div>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="sg-1"><div class="sg-2">
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-base">
</div>
</div>
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-mini">
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>$0.00 with a CONtv trial on Prime Video Channels</span></div>
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary'})[1].text)
print(soup.select('.a-color-secondary')[1].text)
print(soup.select_one('.a-color-secondary:contains("CONtv trial")').text)
```

---

Looping with find_all

```
matches = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary'})
for item in matches:
    if '$' in str(item):
        print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the divs are now **directly** under the `<body>` you can use standard Python indexing. In your real code replace `body` in selector with appropriate element:

```
data = '''<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>MPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)</span></div>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="sg-1"><div class="sg-2">
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-base">
</div>
</div>
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-mini">
<div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span>$0.00 with a CONtv trial on Prime Video Channels</span></div>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select('body > div')[1].text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
$0.00 with a CONtv trial on Prime Video Channels
```

Note the `>` sign in `select()` It means we want all `<div>` **directly** under the `<body>`.